# Unable to access socket.io module from node console

Tags: node.js, sockets

[Please check this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksipr.png), as I can't display it here directly. I have installed socket.io module globally and even i have tried it installing locally inside PushNotification directory. I am still getting the error "Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `socket.io` in global npm `-g`. Instead, install it locally in your project:

```
npm -install socket.io --save
```

Comment: But in that case, will I be able to use it from command line? As far as I know we need to install a module globally when we want to use it from command line (or node bash).

Answer (score 0):

Node has no idea where to find `socket.io` when you install it globally. Global module installs are really only for command line level tools, that have to be linked to your PATH, so that you can call them from outside the node env. The most obvious of which is `npm` e.g. `npm install`.

When you installed socket.io globally, you ended up putting it in `/usr/local/lib`, which is not in the list of locations that node looks for module requires. Node looks in a few locations when it encounters a `require` statement:

1. Node core module
2. if path, look in project path
3. else look in node_modules path

None of these locations match `/usr/local/lib`, so node throws a "not found" error.

Read more about `require` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

To answer your other question, if you install `socket.io` in your node_modules folder, and then in the node command line `require('socket.io')`, it will end up looking in your node_modules folder and finding `socket.io`, so you can easily use it from inside the node command line.